# Firefox does not show anything on tensorboard

Tags: python, firefox, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.jakuba.net/2017/05/30/tensorflow-visualization.html) to learn about tensorflow.

my tensorflow version is 1.1 and I am using Ipython notebook and firefox 38.5 to run my programs.
In this tutorial, there is a part to use tensorboard. I follow everything, however this is what I get:

[image]

a page without showing anything!

I do not know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Both of firefox and tensorflow are pretty old

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the problem here by downloading firefox 38.5 from

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/38.5.0esr/

and running tensorflow 1.1. It seems tensorboard doesn't run smoothly on that particular version of firefox. It's best if you upgrade firefox. I have resolved the issue by running on a later version of firefox such as this

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0b9/linux-x86_64/en-US/

with the same version of tensorflow.

If for whatever reason you don't have administrative privileges you to install, you can use after downloading the above bundle to run tensorboard
as by following step or latest version or insist on running firefox you can do the following ( i was just evaluating on different version for curiosity on one of the last comment on the issue mentioned in the link below)

```
tar -xf firefox-49.0b9.tar.bz2
./firefox -no-remote
```

This seems to be related to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4856